# postgresql insertion through java

Tags: java, postgresql

I've encountered a strange problem. I've got a table, where I want insert data to from java servlet.
The table consits of 3 fields - id - serial (auto inc), name - text, path - text.
So, when I try to insert data with this code:

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
statement = context.getDBConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO systems (name, path) VALUES ('" + request.getParameter("system_name") + "','" + request.getParameter("system_path") + "')");
rs = statement.executeQuery();
rs.close();
```

Nothing happens then. Respone from postresql is "No results were returned by the query" BUT when I insert rows manualy through pgAdmin, their id evaulated like the rows were inserted. For example, I've manualy inserted row, so it got id = 1. Then, after a couple of tries to insert data through servlet, I try to insert data manualy again, and row id is 4, not 2.

**UPDATE**

Modified code, now getting no error, but nothing happens.

```
PreparedStatement statement = null;
  //      ResultSet rs = null;
        statement = context.getDBConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO systems (system_name, folder_path) VALUES (?,?)");
        statement.setString(1, request.getParameter("system_name"));
        statement.setString(2, request.getParameter("system_path"));
        int i = statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of concatenating SQL string

Comment: You need to read the JDBC documentation. See in particular `executeUpdate`. Also, rather than "something like"... show the **exact, unedited error text**. Always.

Comment: You don't use the statement correctly... Use parameters in your prepared statements. Also `path` is a reserved keyword, add backquotes around it.

Comment: Have you called commit() on the connection?

Comment: Can you try by explicitly calling the commit method on the connection object after update. May be your connection object has auto commit set to false.

Comment: Omg, yeah, that was the problem. That's my second sleepless day, soz. Thank you all! Cheers!